# How should I do a DB update using SQLJ in a Liberty Batch (JSR 352) ItemWriter?

Tags: websphere-liberty, jsr352, java-batch

How should I obtain/cache/close my **ConnectionContext** (Connection)?

Should I cache the context in **ItemWriter.open()** and cache across each chunk's **ItemWriter.writeItems()**

What if I want to use DB2-specific APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommended approach is generally to use a get-use-close pattern for SQLJ in the **writeItems()** method run in each chunk.  This is preferred over getting the connection/context in **open()** and caching across chunks.

You can make JDBC driver-specific calls using the **Connection.unwrap()** method.

So something like:

```
public class MyDB2SQLJItemWriter implements ItemWriter {

    DataSource myDataSource; // get via injection (not shown) or however

    // ...

    public void writeItems(List<Object items) throws Exception {

        Connection con = myDataSource.getConnection();
        DB2Connection db2Con = con.unwrap(DB2Connection.class);
        db2Con.setPackagePath(currentPackagePath);  // DB2-specific call
        SqljCtx sqljCtx = new SqljCtx(db2Con);

        // now do SQLJ

        // close SqljCtx AND DB2Connection
        sqljCtx.close();
    }
```

There's also no need to configure your dataSource with the **enableConnectionCasting** attribute, (which adds flexibility not needed here plus opens the door to more complicated issues related to connection caching).

This recommendation extends the general recommendation to follow get-use-close patterns in WebSphere when using JDBC APIs.   Letting WebSphere do the connection pooling provides good performance, better resource utilization and avoids some more complicated pooling scenarios.